# Abrir un contacto de la aplicacion de contactos de android desde mi aplicacion por id

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy iniciandome en Android, y necesito abrir desde mi aplicación el contacto en concreto de la aplicación nativa de contactos pasandole el id, consigo que me abra la aplicación de contactos de android, pero solo la pagina principal, y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, me gustaría hacerlo desde un botón que llama al siguiente método:

```
   public void vercontacto(View view) {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(contactPickerIntent);
    }
```

Lógicamente, cambiando lo que tengo por la manera correcta de hacerlo, el id esta declarado en el comienzo de la clase e inicializado en el método onCreate, ¿como podría hacerlo?.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas abrir ùnicamente la aplicaciòn puedes realizarlo de esta forma, mediante el paquete de la aplicaciòn:

```
public void showContactsApp(){

    Intent intent  = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity"));
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Si lo que deseas es abrir la información de un contacto especifico por su ID, se realiza de esta forma:

```
public void openContactById(int contactID){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```